# Introduction to Pseudodifferential operators

Tags: analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I'm interested in elementary introduction to pseduodifferential operators and its application to hyperbolic PDE's. I know measure theory, Fourier analysis and some elementary(linear) hyperbolic PDE's but not functional analysis, distributions, Sobolev spaces,etc. Can you recommend suitable intro text? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is of course Hörmander's magnum opus *The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators* (Springer); pseudodifferential operators are discussed in [volume III](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-3-540-13828-0?otherVersion=978-3-540-49937-4).

Less technical is Michael Taylor's book [*Pseudodifferential Operators*](http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/mt1.html) (Princeton University Press). He also has a set of [lecture notes](http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/msripde.pdf) and a pdf of his book [*Pseudodifferential Operators and Nonlinear PDEs*](http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/NLIN.pdf) (Birkhäuser) on his website.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest introduction is "An Introduction to Pseudo-differential Operators by "M. W. Wong". 
However it is not so general as Hörmander or Taylor. It develops the theory only for the classes $S^m_{1, 0}$. The requisites are very modest. Another nice reading is "Pseudo-differential and Singular Integral Operators" by "H. Abels".

Answer (score 3):

The best introduction is Raymond *Elementary Introduction to the Theory of Pseudodifferential Operators* CRC Press.